# Does Odata adaptor support "Patch" request with "$expand" query during CRUD operations?

Tags: odata, odata-v4, http-patch

I have a component with **ODataAdaptor** as a data source, now i would like to make a **Patch** request with **$expand** query like i make for GET request(since GET request openly supports $expand query). But i don't have an idea whether it is accepted or is there any other way i can look into to approach this issue?

Actual request: http://localhost:49807/odata/Orders(10249)

Expected request: http://localhost:49807/odata/Orders(10249)/?$expand=OrderDetail($select=CustomerID)

with $expand query in Patch request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily Patch to nested properties, this is well documented restriction. However if you want to patch a single object, and return a result with the expanded path you have suggested then there are two simple steps to achieve this:

1. Add the `[EnableQuery]` attribute to your *Patch* endpoint method.
2. Make sure your patch response returns an IQueryable result, or that you aggressively include / eager load all the potential expansions to your object response inside the method body, then the serializer will return the expanded object graph.